# How do I remove all the lines in a text file that are present in another text file in Windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have two files: `content.txt` and `remove.txt`. I would like to run `.cmd` script that removes all lines from `content.txt` that are in `remove.txt`. The result should go to `result.txt`.

For example:

`content.txt`

```
abc
1234
hello
qwerty
```

`remove.txt`

```
abc
hello
def
```

`result.txt`

```
1234
qwerty
```

This question is the same but using Perl: [Removing lines in one file that are present in another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239225/removing-lines-in-one-file-that-are-present-in-another-file). I can only use standard Windows tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
findstr /L /v /X /g:remove.txt content.txt>result.txt
```

/X means "match lines exactly"

?L means "literally - not regex"

/v means "not -matching"

/g:filename is filename to use as string-(exclusion)-source

/I would make case-insensitive.

Comment: This worked, thanks. Something to be aware of is that spaces on the end of lines matter. My `remove.txt` file had trailing spaces on each line due to an upstream batch script.