# Remove all the lines in a text file that contain text in another file in C#

Tags: c#, console-application

I would like to the same as [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35746578/how-do-i-remove-all-the-lines-in-a-text-file-that-are-present-in-another-text-fi) however in C#.

In other words, I have 3 text files:

- `content.txt`
- `remove.txt`
- `result.txt`

I would like to remove all the lines in `content.txt` that contain any of the lines in `remove.txt` and output the results into `result.txt`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try *Linq*: write to `result.txt` all lines from `content.txt` where line is not in `remove.txt`:

```
 using System.IO;
 using System.Linq;

 ...

 HashSet<string> toRemove = new HashSet<string>(File.ReadLines(@"remove.txt"));

 File.WriteAllLines(@"result.txt", File
   .ReadLines(@"content.txt")
   .Where(line => !toRemove.Contains(line)));
```

Comment: Thank you, picked as solution.

Answer (score 1):

First read the files

```
var contentLines = File.ReadAllLines("content.txt");
var removeLines = File.ReadAllLines("remove.txt");
```

Then we can create ResultLines by utilising Linq query where we iterate through contentLines and check that the content line doesn't exist in remove lines collection

```
var resultLines = contentLines.Where(contentLine => removeLines.All(r => r != contentLine)).ToList();
```

And finally write resultLines to a new file called result.txt

```
 File.WriteAllLines("result.txt", resultLines);
```

**Full Sample**

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace Sandbox
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // ReadFiles
            var contentLines = File.ReadAllLines("content.txt");
            var removeLines = File.ReadAllLines("remove.txt");

            // Iterate through content lines and check that it doesn't exists in removeLines by using LINQ
            var resultLines = contentLines.Where(contentLine => removeLines.All(r => r != contentLine)).ToList();

            // Write result.txt
            File.WriteAllLines("result.txt", resultLines);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a start

```
string[]  allLinesRemove = File.ReadAllLines(filePath_of_Remove.txt);
string[]  allLinesContent = File.ReadAllLines(filePath_of_Content.txt);
```

Now use LINQ or For Loops to get what you need to a 3rd array. *I Left it to you*

Then output the results

Comment: That's not an answer. You've provided half of the code.